# CSS three columns with middle column fixed width

Tags: html, css

I need to position an element in between two other elements. The middle element has a specified width, but the side elements must calculate their width automatically (for different screen widths). If I add the left element it completely forgets about the "margin: 0 auto" on the middle one, and adding an element on the right just places it below, because the middle element is already occupying the space with "float: right"

What I have tried:

HTML:

```
<div class="middle"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    height: 200px;
}
.left {
    background: red;
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.middle {
    background: green;
    width: 400px;
    float: right;
}
.right {
    background: blue;
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here is JSFiddle showing it: http://jsfiddle.net/xnwv8scp/2/

Comment: You should use flexbox.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=css+three+column+middle+fixed+width

Comment: Thanks @CBroe I was searching with a lot more complex terms, I guess you have to search everything dumbed down now.

Comment: OT: I wouldn’t call that “dumbing down”, but rather “abstracting the problem” ;-) If your search terms focus too much on specifics of your own iteration of the problem (or what you think those might be), it gets less likely that other people will have used the same terms to describe it. It’s a balance that you have to strike, between being specific enough, and yet generic enough at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

You can try flexbox:

```css
body {
  display: flex;  /* Magic begins */
}
.middle {
  width: 400px;   /* Specified width */
}
.left, .right {
  flex: 1;        /* Fill available space */
}
body > * {
  min-width: 0;   /* Widths ignore the content */
  height: 200px;
}
.left { background: red; }
.middle { background: green; }
.right { background: blue; }
```

```html
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="middle"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the CSS table solution which works on more browsers - IE8+

http://jsfiddle.net/xnwv8scp/3/

```css
body {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0;
}
body > div {
    display: table-cell;
}
.left {
    background: red;
}
.middle {
    background: green;
    width: 400px;
}
.right {
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="middle"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the following is very close to what you want - adjust overflow as required.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Three column layout</title>
<style>
body { margin: 0; overflow: hidden }
#X { position: absolute; height: 200px; overflow: auto; padding: 9px; border: 1px solid red; margin: 9px 210px 0 9px; left: 0; right: 50% }
#Y { position: absolute; height: 200px; overflow: auto; padding: 9px; border: 1px solid red; margin: 9px -200px 0 -200px; left: 50%; right: 50% }
#Z { position: absolute; height: 200px; overflow: auto; padding: 9px; border: 1px solid red; margin: 9px 9px 0 210px; left: 50%; right: 0 }
</style>
<div id=X>
Left content
</div>
<div id=Y>
Middle content
</div>
<div id=Z>
Right content
</div>
```